# Sumifs with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function, sumifs

I have attempted using different VBA subs to pull data from my [MasterRenamed] datasheet into my [P&L] sheet using Category, and date ranges.

While I got the first to work, I was unable to figure out how to make it dynamic (i.e. I could only do one item at a time).  I completely failed with the second for whatever reason.

I would upload the workbook but maybe because I am new to the forum I am not allowed to upload docs yet(?). I am not set on any particular code format as long as it works. I would certainly appreciate some guidance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please share actual code snippets of what you've tried along with how its not working. Screenshots will make it very difficult for anyone to reproduce the code.

Comment: Just copy and paste the code in your question, don't copy and paste it into an excel worksheet and then copy and paste a snippet of that!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your responses.  I was able to figure it out, and believe i've come up with a pretty good solution comparatively to what i was able to find online.

this macro uses a search list in excel (col k) to search through the data set (bank and credit card statements) and returns combined totals (like Excel's native consolidate  function) down the column search list.

Sub Search_and_Consolidate_Sums()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("MasterRenamedx")

ws1.Select

Dim lrow1 As Long, lrow2 As Long
' first lrow is used in the lookup data range, the second lrow is for the lookup list.

lrow1 = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

lrow2 = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rng1 As Range ' lookup list

Set rng1 = Range("k1")

stDate = Range("J1") ' start & end dates

EndDate = Range("j2")

Dim Dates As Range, Categories As Range, Debits As Range, Credits As Range ' Data range

Set Dates = Sheets("MasterRenamedx").Range("B2:B" & lrow1)

Set Categories = Sheets("MasterRenamedx").Range("C2:C" & lrow1)

Set Debits = Sheets("MasterRenamedx").Range("E2:E" & lrow1)

For i = 2 To lrow2

mytotals = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Debits, Dates, _

">=" & stDate, Dates, "<=" & EndDate, Categories, Cells(i, 11))

Cells(i, 12) = mytotals

Next i

End Sub